# unresponsivness with buttons on phonegap

Tags: ios, html, phonegap

I am trying to design a simple game on phone gap with HTML5. On the phone if I try to click a button it will only work if my finger doesn't move at all while on the button. This means it only works if you tap it slowly and carefully.

Is there any way to make it so I can click the button and always get it to respond even if my finger moves a little?

Comment: Could you share a piece of your code? Not entirely sure what you're talking about. You might be doing some simple drawing on a canvas, that'd be another story then! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are waiting for a `click` event you maybe facing a 300ms delay problem which is nicely handled by [FastClick package](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick)

Comment: Does this work as an application or only on browsers?

Comment: It will work on cordova the same as it works on mobile browsers

Comment: If you're using Ionic, simply add the `tappable` property to your element.